# Prevent forwarding from being "too liberal"

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, enable-if

I've implemented a function for performing an "in-place object recycle" hack based on the idea of the *deplorable just-plain-wrongheadedness* assignment-by-placement-new example shown in GotW #23 and referred to in #28.

(Yes, yes, I know... but that hack has actually shown quite useful as a very noticeable optimization in an application which processes a lot of messages, and I guess it's safe enough if used correctly.)

The code compiles without warnings on clang++ 3.5 and "works fine", but it is somewhat too liberal in my opinion as it allows some implicit conversions that might happen accidentially and which may be undesirable:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value, T&>::type
recycle(T& obj, T&& other)  noexcept
{ obj.~T(); new (&obj) T(other);  return obj; }

template<typename T, typename... A>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_nothrow_constructible<T>::value && std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value, T&>::type
recycle(T& obj, A&&... arg) noexcept
{ obj.~T(); new (&obj) T(arg...); return obj; }


int main()
{
    struct foo
    {
        foo() noexcept {}
        explicit foo(float) noexcept {}
    };

    foo b;
    recycle(b, foo());     // OK, calls #1, move-constructing from default temporary
    recycle(b, foo(1.0f)); // OK, as above, but non-default temporary
    recycle(b, 5.0f);      // OK, calls #2, forwarding and move-constructing
    recycle(b, 5.0);       // succeeds calling #2 (undesired implicit double --> float conversion)
    recycle(b, 5);         // succeeds calling #2 (undesired implicit int ---> float conversion)
    recycle(b, b);         // succeeds, but should probably fail a runtime check (undefined behavior)

    return 0;
}
```

The fact that some calls compile just fine when you wouldn't expect them to may be because the template parameter pack catches "everything", but I'm still surprised how it can work alltogether since `foo`'s constructor is `explicit`, and either way the template must call it. I'm not sure how it can convert integers and doubles to floats there without clang++ emitting even as much as a warning.

This makes me wonder whether I am assuming something wrong about what the `explicit` keyword does on a constructor.

Self-assignment (which will invoke undefined behavior) is a non-issue for me since trying to recycle an object with itself shows some serious brain failure in the first place (so I've decided not to add a runtime check for that), but accidentially calling a function with an implicitly convertible parameter is something that could happen pretty easily, and something I'd like to catch with a compiler error if that's possible.

Basically what I might need is something like `get_constructor_args<T>` to put inside another `enable_if` with `is_convertible`. Or something... concepts?

Is there a way of achieving this kind of thing with C++11 (or C++14, if you will)?

Comment: [Use `{}` to catch narrowing conversions](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea5c188e4ab2b0b1). Also, your first `recycle` always copies since `other` is an lvalue (it has a name). Use `std::forward` to have it move when passed a temporary. Finally, `recycle(b, 5.0f);` doesn't move construct anything.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that `recycle(T&,T&&)` is an optimization vs. move assignment, unless your move assignment is horribly broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<class T, class...Args>
using safe_to_recycle = std::integral_constant<bool,
  std::is_nothrow_constructible<T, Args...>::value
  && std::is_nothrow_destroyable<T>::value
>;


template<typename T, typename... Args>
std::enable_if_t<safe_to_recycle<T,Args...>::value, T&>
recycle(T& obj, Args&&... args)  noexcept
{
  obj.~T();
  new (&obj) T{std::forward<Args>(args)...};
  return obj;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
std::enable_if_t<safe_to_recycle<T,Args...>::value, T&>
recycle_explicit(T& obj, Args&&... args)  noexcept
{
  obj.~T();
  new (&obj) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  return obj;
}

template<typename T, typename U>
std::enable_if_t<
  std::is_same<std::decay_t<T>,std::decay_t<U>>::value &&
  safe_to_recycle<T,U>::value,
  T&
>
recycle(T& obj, U&& rhs)  noexcept
{
  if (&obj == &rhs) return obj;
  obj.~T();
  new (&obj) T{std::forward<U>(rhs)};
  return obj;
}

template<typename T, typename U>
std::enable_if_t<
  std::is_same<std::decay_t<T>,std::decay_t<U>>::value &&
  safe_to_recycle<T,U>::value,
  T&
>
recycle_explicit(T& obj, U&& rhs)  noexcept
{
  if (&obj == &rhs) return obj;
  obj.~T();
  new (&obj) T(std::forward<U>(rhs));
  return obj;
}
```

If you lack C++14, write your own `enable_if_t` and `decay_t`.

You can drop that run time check if you want.  Just eliminate the last 2 recyles.  The variardic will handle move assignment etc.

Note that an explicit constructor will not be called by `recycle` -- you have to `recycle( obj, T(5.0f) )`.  And `recycle_explicit` will do narrowing conversions.

Comment: The `T&, U&&` versions of both `recycle` and `recycle_explicit` have superfluous pack expansions causing compiler errors, but after removing these, it seems to work exactly as intended, provided that `enable_if_t` and `decay_t` are present. Thank you very much. Now I'll need to spend the evening figuring out _how and why exactly_ it works :-)

Comment: @Damon that is why there is an edit button.  :)  The basic idea is that perfect forwarding ... well, forwards.  So that handles most cases.  The special case code detects one-arg pseudo-copy constructors, and does the pointer test.  As noted, it is probably not worth it --  you should maybe assert and continue on.  The `safe_to_recycle` just packs two tests (nothrow construction and destriction) into one test, so you cannot throw `recycle` in a way that could cause it to throw while the object does not exist (which would lead to double-destruction and UB)